# delphi: commandline passing xml with quotes

Tags: xml, windows, delphi, console

I am facing an issue. I am passing a xml with attributes along with other params to a console app.

I am giving the string that am sending.

```
/menu mycmd "print abc=myfile.txt,XML=<Action UIStatus="011" _UIDS="Action" StartingNumber="00004" EndingNumber="00006" FromLabel="Include" All="TRUE" />"
```

The string I am getting in console is

```
/menu mycmd print file=myfile.txt,XML=<Action UIStatus=011 _UIDS=Action StartingNumber=00004 EndingNumber=00004 FromLabel=Include All=TRUE />
```

The quotes are missing.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are absorbed by the shell. If you want your quotes to not be absorbed, escape them. I.e.

```
/menu mycmd \"print abc=myfile.txt,XML=\"
```

On what kind of console are you working? What stands the `/menu` for? Is that your command line prompt?

Comment: Thanks Erik, \menu is another param. I tried with I replaced quotes with  "\". still it didnt worked, I am getting only \ (ie, without quotes).

Comment: With what kind of programs are you working? Unix/Linux Shell (Bash) or on Windows? Which program sends the string? And which program should reveice the string? MySQL? PHP? Perl? JavaScript? Java? What are you using? And what do you mean with *passing*?

Comment: Windows with Delphi.I meant calling an app with arguments.

Comment: I am using CommandProcessor: TCommandProcessor;       CommandProcessor := TCommandProcessor.CreateOn(Command);
        CommandProcessor.DoCommands;
command is the string that I added on question.

Comment: Ok, then I cannot help you. But you should add to your question (and to its subject) on which system you are working (delphi, windows). Then you will get appropriate help soon.